# Extracting multiple text field data from single cell in database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a small form [here](http://www.tauschpakete.de/mach-mit/) that users fill but the form saves all the data in a singular cell in the database. So how do I extract the data if each field from it?

Following is an example cell data (It has all the data of the complete form):-

```
{
    "18":{"name":"W\u00e4hle dein Wunschpaket","value":"BASIC \"Bis zu 10\u20ac\"","value_raw":"BASIC \"Bis zu 10\u20ac\"","id":18,"type":"select"},
    "11":{"name":"Geschlecht","value":"Weiblich","value_raw":"Weiblich","id":11,"type":"select"},
    "15":{"name":"Hauttyp","value":"Hell","value_raw":"Hell","id":15,"type":"select"},
    "14":{"name":"Kleidergr\u00f6\u00dfe","value":"XS","value_raw":"XS","id":14,"type":"select"},
    "20":{"name":"Geburtsdatum","value":"24.05.1991","id":20,"type":"text"},
    "16":{"name":"Schuhgr\u00f6\u00dfe","value":"35","value_raw":"35","id":16,"type":"select"},
    "13":{"name":"Interessen","value":"","value_raw":"","id":13,"type":"checkbox"},
    "17":{"name":"Lieblingsfarbe","value":"","id":17,"type":"text"},
    "21":{"name":"Wunsch-Tauschpartner","value":"","value_raw":"","id":21,"type":"checkbox"},
    "8":{"name":"\u00dcber dich & Besondere Anmerkungen","value":"","id":8,"type":"textarea"},
    "0":{"name":"Name","value":"laksh khamesra","id":0,"type":"name","first":"laksh","middle":"","last":"khamesra"},
    "1":{"name":"E-Mail-Adresse","value":"abc@xyz.com","id":1,"type":"email"},
    "4":{"name":"Stra\u00dfe & Hausnummer","value":"1","id":4,"type":"text"},
    "19":{"name":"Telefonnummer","value":"","id":19,"type":"text"},
    "6":{"name":"PLZ","value":"313001","id":6,"type":"text"},
    "7":{"name":"Stadt","value":"udaipur","id":7,"type":"text"},
    "10":{"name":"Land","value":"India","id":10,"type":"text"},
    "22":{"name":"Wie hast du von uns erfahren?","value":"Instagram","value_raw":"Instagram","id":22,"type":"select"}
}
```

P.S. I can't make it not store all data in singular cell because I can't edit the original code. I must separate data of each text field from the cell. But how?

[image]

Comment: what's the expected result for this?

Comment: you extract data like you normally do, use a `SELECT` statement, since you don't have codes yet, here's the idea: connect to db, create your select statement, execute the query, fetch the rows, profit

Comment: I would suggest that you don't store all the data in a single 'cell'. Failing that, you might take a look at MySQL's JSON tools

Comment: @Strawberry I am using a Wordpress plugin to make the form and I checked their code and I couldn't find the code where to store data to database, hence, I can't edit it to not store all data in one cell. Any ideas?

Comment: The data is valid JSON -- either use `json_decode` on the php-side to create a php datastructure, or use the json-possibilities of the database (I don't know what mysql has to offer nowadays). Note that it seems that a php-array with numerical keys was serialized to json as an object with string-properties "0", "1" and so on

Comment: With the help of `json_decode()` function, you can extract the data. [link](https://www.unserialize.com/s/0138ca4f-6a39-b0e8-6ba9-000070f6931e).